# Ubuntu 12.04 64bit doesn't shutdown properly

Tags: 12.04, shutdown

i searched a lot for a solutions to this problem
i have an two  Ubuntu 12.04 installs both have the same issue , after invoking a shutdown with varied ways `sudo init 0`, "sudo halt" , menu shutdown, but they all have the same result,
all goes good until it reaches

```
Will now halt 
[time] power down
```

then it hangs there forever, i tried to modify "/etc/default/grub"
adding `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="acpi=force"` then tried `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash acpi=force"` and updating grub each time in vain
note that restarting the machine is not affected, because it reboots smoothly
I'm using GPT/UEFI install for x64 12.04 both,
and in the grub added this entry which also hangs

```
menuentry "System shutdown" {
    echo "System shutting down..."
    halt
}
```

any idea of how to fix this would be appreciated.
**UPDATE**
/var/log/syslog is empty before and after shutting down-starting
**note** that using a direct restart (like `sudo reboot`) works perfectly, but shutting down and starting manually is faulty

Comment: why this downvote? i have a question that i asked , if there is anything wrong just comment and i'll fix it!!!!!!!

Comment: Maybe it's downvoted because Ubuntu 12.04 is no longer supported. It's time to upgrade to 14.04 or 14.10.

Comment: i think you should do some research before rushing to conclusions, 12.04 is supported until April 2017, which 2 years ahead, see here https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Releases

Comment: That is only for security updates, not for other software updates. The only reason that they give security updates for that extra 2 years anyway is so that servers can stay secure for another 2 years while Canonical waits for the administrators to upgrade them.

Comment: Fuzzy is wrong. Ignore what he says. 12.04 is still perfectly on topic. They probably downvoted because the question is quite easily researchable I think...

Comment: @Tim  while it is indeed easly found on the net and even on this website,though i really did my research and all solutions didn't fit, that's why i posted this question

Comment: Fair enough. Just saying why there were down votes. Did my answer help?

Comment: unfortunately, it didn't, as you explained , it only halts!! it says "will halt now" then "[time] Power down" and that's it, i have to push the button again

Answer (score -1, accepted):

all i had to do is to update the UEFI Firmware (BIOS), and the funny thing is that i didn't do it to solve this issue but to solve another, now my computer shuts down properly, thanks for the ideas.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I cannot solve the problem with the GUI shutdown method, but I had the same problem.

The command

```
sudo shutdown now
```

is equivalent to

```
sudo halt
```

which is simply halting the machine. That means it is simply halting the OS and stopping all CPUs. Once the system is cleanly halted, the user may safely hit the Power button on his computer manually.

So you can just press the power button if you want.

However, to solve that you can use this command

```
sudo shutdown -P now
```

The `poweroff`, `shutdown -P now`, and `halt -p` commands all do the same thing as `halt` alone, **while additionally sending an ACPI command to signal the power supply unit to disconnect the main power**. This prevents you from having to physically push the Power button on your computer.

That suggests you can also use this command:

```
sudo poweroff
```

or this:

```
sudo halt -p
```

Answer (score -1):

we meet again ;)

Best thing to do is to check BIOS before doing anything. Set it to default and try it again. I'm sure your system is up to date on all software, this is 99% a hardware, not a software issue. My Sony Vaio SVS had the same issue until I flashed new BIOS.

P.S. If you are running dual boot, try to update your BIOS via Windows.

Comment: first there is no BIOS on my machine , instead UEFI, and it is up to date, i checked that

Comment: Did you try edit Grub on boot with "acpi=off"?

Comment: yes, read the question! off force everything

Comment: I started googling a little about that problem, its kinda common :P Try running: sudo shutdown -h now

Comment: i did all the googling, i didn't just post a question waiting for easy answer, and yes i'm aware of the command which in turn not working as it leads to the same result, sorry but this problem is really frustrating, i placed a bounty with all i got, i'm not able to comment anymore, just to get new ideas , thank you for your time

Comment: There could be XY solutions to your problem, it is a common issue, but many different solutions to it. It could be some APCI controling indicator or power management process like TLP. Or a Broadcom WiFi card driver or a bug in kernel. In any case something installed on both machines/installs. If you try a clean install do you get a same issue? Backup with SystemBack to external Ext4 HDD and maybe try a clean install? Powerdown from Live CD is working flawless?

Comment: kernel issues are not related because i had two different kernel versions both with the same issue, and both installs are on same machine, i retried all the above mentioned ways, and even saw the post on ubuntuforums u gave me, each one there has cause which doesn't apply for me, i have proper unmounting, i have good drivers , i don't have cairo...just to tell you, my machine has also win7 which shuts properly, so hardware too is good

Comment: @younes restart your machine and open System Log, under syslog find the time hh:mm of your restart and check for errors and add them to your question please.

Answer (score -2):

It is because of your computer is not really eligible for using ubuntu or it maybe because of you are using an old and customized version of ubuntu !
So, Its usually seen in customized versions of ubuntu.Some Ubuntus made in Ubuntu customization kits had this trouble before with me...
So I did install another version of ubuntu to fix this problem.
You easilly upgrade if you are really using an ubuntu version....
Just do upgrade to fix this problem.
This problem is just because of the Shutdown button isn't setted up currectly !
So try installing a fresh version of ubuntu which can be downloaded from [Ubuntu.com](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop)
If you still face some problems then it  might be because of your system problems...
Or you can simply try using this code :

```
% sudo grub-update
```

(Type this code in Terminal and Press enter)
...............................................
If it doesn't works, then try this :

- Open Terminal emulator by Pressing Ctrl+Alt+T together.
- `sudo vi /etc/default/grub` type this code in it and press enter !
- Locate the following part in the loaded content - `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT=”quiet splash”`
- Add acpi=force at the end as shown here: `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT=”quiet splash acpi=force”`
- Save and exit using :wq
- Finally run this command and press enter,

  `% sudo update-grub`

I hope this will work for sure.This worked for me when I had the same problem with my Ubuntu 12.04 ! So I think this will work ! :)

ref: [unixmen.com](http://www.unixmen.com/fix-shutdown-power-computer-ubuntu-14-04/)